# General performance issue on IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, telerik

Good morning,

I'm working on implementing a Telerik RadGrid for my company, but have found it difficult to optimize the grid to work efficiently on IE; some of our clients primarily uses an older version (v.7) of that specific browser.

The use case is one such as the user will be able to specify the group (either Red or Green) and then a type (the Red grid has ~20 different types, the Green has one).

The issue I'm facing is that the Green grid takes nearly 9 seconds to load on IE. 
These are the loadtimes on different browsers:

- **Chrome**, **Firefox**: 4 seconds to load (which is acceptable, but not good).
- **Edge**: 6 secounds
- **IE** (latest version): 8.6 seconds.

I've already checked the view that both the grids use to get its data from and it loads in less than a second, so that wouldn't be a problem.

I'm assuming it could be something with the client side operations (hiding / displaying columns, enabling/disabling buttons, setting column's datafields etc).

The reason I am posting this is to see if there are any potential bottlenecks that all of you might have noticed while either working with RadGrid / GridView etc.

I'm not really sure what code might be relevant for this issue, so if you need any snippets etc, I'd happily get it on request.

Thanks for your consideration.

Regards,

Joakim

Comment: "_...if there are any potential bottlenecks..._" -> "_...our clients primarily uses an older version (**v.7**)..._"

Comment: Clearly I understand that IE isn't the optimal browser (especially in it's earlier iterations), but we can't tell the client (a multi-million corporation) what to use as they have a history of not listening to technical advice.

Comment: `bottlenecks` ... telerik ... no more needs to be said

Comment: I have hard time understanding how Customer can have IE7 or Xp/vista ... 
Do they understand that even MS don't wanna deal with those thing ever again calling end of life and end of support on it. That having a 2002 laptop with out any security update with full acces to web is a bad idea. Now i just make my pagen as attractive as possible on IE11 and let the IE5 user deal with it. They have old Vb6 application only useable on IE7 and less , Use virtual machine for this. I hope there is a special place in hell for them. Look what they did to us!

Comment: This is probably because of a large DOM tree. Reduce column count, reduce page size (enable paging if you have not already), look into displaying additional information from rarely used columns in a popup (tooltip or window). Also, look into using virtualization